# flutter: how to make animated list sliding item overflow hidden?

Tags: flutter

the right side is an animated list, and how to hide list tile overflow like the picture below.

the list tile code is below

```dart
return Slidable(
  actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
  secondaryActions: <Widget>[
    IconSlideAction(
      color: Colors.red,
      iconWidget: Icon(Icons.delete, size: 24),
      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
      onTap: () {
      },
    ),
  ],
...
```

and the animated list code is below,

```dart
Expanded(
  child: AnimatedList(
    key: _listKey,
    controller: ScrollController(),
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    initialItemCount: this._programDetails.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, animation) {
      return SlideTransition(
        position: Tween<Offset>(
          begin: const Offset(0, -5),
          end: Offset(0, 0),
        ).animate(animation),
        child: _buildProgramDetailTile(context, index),
     );
   },
 ),
),
```

and can anyone help to use which widget to resolve this issue?

[image: the issue page]

Answer (score 0):

upgrade flutter_slidable to 1.0.0 to solve the issue.